# Как перезаписать посты в кастомном типа записей в обратном порядке?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, order

Мне необходимо перезаписать записи из кастомного типа записей в обратном порядке.
Я пробовал добавить такой код в файл functions.php

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'otcheti'
);
$othecti = get_posts($args);
$othecti_revers = array_reverse(get_posts($args));
for ($i = 0; $i < count($othecti); $i++) {
    $newOthect = $othecti_revers[$i];
    $newOthect->ID = $othecti[$i];
    wp_insert_post($newOthect);
}
```

К сожалению, перезапись не происходит.
Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

Может есть какой-нибудь более простой способ перезаписать посты в кастомном типе записей обратном порядке?

Answer (score 0):

> Может есть какой-нибудь более простой способ перезаписать посты в
>   кастомном типе записей обратном порядке?

В массив $args добавь параметр `orederby` с нужным значением "обратного"

См:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters
https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-sortirovki-i-poryadka

Comment: Я вроде бы массив разворачиваю с помощью array_reverse. У меня больше с перезаписатью проблемы.

Comment: я почитал по ссылка вдоль и поперек и ответ, как перезаписать записи в обратном порядке не увидел. Можно более развернутый ответ, почему array_reverse не подходит? И что за значение 'обратного'?

Comment: Да какой нафик `array_reverse`! Не майся фигнёй. `get_posts` СРАЗУ сформирует что нужно и как нужно. Параметры те же, что и у `wp_query`

Comment: И что с того что формирует? Ты читал вопрос, написано, что нужно перезаписать записи. Вывести посты я могу в любом порядке где угодно хоть по порядку, хоть задом наперед, как угодно. Я перезаписать не мог, а не вывести в обратном порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

В общем есть смысл использовать вот такой цикл и обновлять только те поля, которые нужно обновить, а не пытаться полностью перезаписать обьект:

```
for ($i= 0; $i < count($posts); $i++) {
    wp_update_post(array(
        'ID' =>  $posts[$i]->ID,
        'post_title' => $posts_reverse[$i]->post_title,
        'post_content' => $posts_reverse[$i]->post_content,
    ));
}
```